# APK signed with a restricted certificate

Tags: android, certificate, google-play-services, jks, google-play-console

Getting error when uploading app into playstore

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a restricted certificate. You
>   need to upload an APK signed with your own certificate.

signed with:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks
-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias

apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk
```

Comment: have you tried using the standard tool provided by Android Studio to generate new certificates?

Comment: @AlbertoM no its compiled apk

Comment: you can still create certificates with Android Studio and then sign it with the cli command

Comment: ok let me try it

Comment: @AlbertoM stilling getting .You uploaded an APK that is signed with a restricted certificate. You need to upload an APK signed with your own certificate.

Comment: @AlbertoM I have created certificate with android studio now

Answer (score 0):

To create keyStore.

1. Go to Build->Generate Signed APK
2. click on Create New with required Path
3. Enter password and alias for keystore.
4. After successful creation of Keystore create SignApk with same and upload to store

Comment: I have only apk file

Comment: Can you check your application package name or bundle Id with Play Store?
means there may be another application exist with play store with same application id.